# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Confirm Password TextBox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, passwords

Right so I want a password textbox and a confirm password textbox but I am unsure how to set these up correctly.

I have the following:

```
    // This is where the user will enter the password for the product owner they wish to add.
    private void textBoxPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Each character of the password will display as an asterisk.
        textBoxPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
        // Control to allow a max password length of 15 charachers.
        textBoxPassword.MaxLength = 15;
    }

    // This is where the user will re-enter the password for the product owner they wish to add.
    private void textBoxConfirmPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Each character of the password will display as an asterisk.
        textBoxConfirmPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
        // Control to allow a max password length of 15 charachers.
        textBoxConfirmPassword.MaxLength = 15;
        // If statements to ensure that the passwords are the same.
        if (textBoxPassword.Text != textBoxConfirmPassword.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match.");
            textBoxConfirmPassword.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
```

It works okay up to a point. The only problem is that as soon as I begin typing in the confirm password field, the "Passwords do not match" message displays after I enter every character. I only want it to display at the end of the string.

I'm sure the solution is simple but I'm self teaching myself how to use Visual and I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im also a beginner, but i hope my advice will help you.

The problem is that **textBoxConfirmPassword_TextChanged** is checking the matching of passwords every time you type a symbol into it. To fix it, i can offer to add some code:
instead of

```
if (textBoxPassword.Text != textBoxConfirmPassword.Text)
```

try

```
if (textBoxPassword.TextLenght==textBoxConfirmPassword.Textlength && textBoxPassword.Text != textBoxConfirmPassword.Text)
{   
// does not match    
}
```

So when you reach same number of symbols in your **textBoxConfirmPassword** as in **textBoxPassword** it will say if it matches or not. But you would be able to add symbols after the message error, so i reccomend to clear **textBoxConfirmPassword.Text** before showing error message, like this

```
textBoxConfirmPassword.Text="";
MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match.");...
```

Or you can block the input or do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the textbox's TextChanged event to check the passwords, use the textbox's Validating event. That event occurs when the user attempts to change the focus to another control. If the passwords don't match you can prevent the focus from changing by setting e.Cancel to true.

Comment: How would I go about coding that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtpassword_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtpassword.TextChanged
    txtpassword.PasswordChar = "*"
    txtpassword.MaxLength = 16
End Sub

Private Sub txtconfirmpassword_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtconfirmpassword.TextChanged
    txtconfirmpassword.PasswordChar = "*"
    txtconfirmpassword.MaxLength = 16

    If txtconfirmpassword.Text.Length = txtpassword.Text.Length Then
        If txtconfirmpassword.Text <> txtpassword.Text Then
            MsgBox("Password do not match")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```